# Getting max text length out of all rows

Tags: javascript, jointjs

How to get the length of all the text from all rows. I have problem with variable scoping. I am getting only the text length of last row.

Code:

```
pointerclick: function (evt, x, y) {
    var className = evt.target.parentNode.getAttribute('class');

    if (className === 'element-tool-remove')
    {
        this.model.remove();
        console.log("element removed");

        var embeddedCells = parent1.getEmbeddedCells();

        var t = new Array();      
        var maxTextLength;
        for(var d = 0; d < embeddedCells.length; d++)
        {
            t[d] = embeddedCells[d].attributes.attrs.text.text.length;
            var maxTextLength = Math.max(t[d]);
            //console.log("max text length is: " + maxTextLength);
        }
        console.log("max text length is: " + maxTextLength); // printing only last element's text length but not the max value out of all
    }
    joint.dia.CellView.prototype.pointerclick.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

How do I get the max value out of all the rows?

Comment: what is the value of this variable `t[d]` every time it iterates?

Comment: @DyrandzFamador That depends on the input text I am passing in

Comment: @DyrandzFamador so Every time when I pass an text into input box and clikk submit, a new row is added. If there are 4 rows like that, I want to get the max text length out of all the rows

Comment: does this variable `t[d]` contains a series of value? like (2,3,5) ?

Comment: @DyrandzFamador yes it does. I checked it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
pointerclick: function (evt, x, y) {
    var className = evt.target.parentNode.getAttribute('class');

    if (className === 'element-tool-remove')
    {
        this.model.remove();
        console.log("element removed");

        var embeddedCells = parent1.getEmbeddedCells();

        var t = new Array();      
        var maxTextLength = 0;
        for(var d = 0; d < embeddedCells.length; d++)
        {
            t[d] = embeddedCells[d].attributes.attrs.text.text.length;
            maxTextLength = Math.max(t[d], maxTextLength);
            //console.log("max text length is: " + maxTextLength);
        }
        console.log("max text length is: " + maxTextLength); // printing only last element's text length but not the max value out of all
    }
    joint.dia.CellView.prototype.pointerclick.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

I've assigned 0 as a default to the maxTextLength variable and in the loop I'm replacing the value of maxTextLength if the new value is larger. I do not have a way to test that code, but it should work.

Comment: i think this will add all the value instead of just getting the highest length.

Comment: @metal03326 could you please also explain this line: `maxTextLength = Math.max(t[d], maxTextLength);` Thank you